# EL expression in JSF f:param name attribute

Tags: jsf

I tried the following:

Something like the facelet I used:

```
...
<h:button value="x" outcome="nextpage">
  <f:param name="#{myBean.PARAM_NAME}" value="someValue"/>
</h:button>
...
```

Something like the managed bean I used as a controller for the previous facelet:

```
@Named(value="myBean")
@ViewScoped
public MyBean implements Serializable
{
  private static final String PARAM_NAME = "paramName";

  public String getPARAM_NAME()
  { return PARAM_NAME };

  @PostConstruct
  public void init()
  {
    String passedParamValue = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(
PARAM_NAME );
    ...
  }
}
```

The advantage of this is : I use the param name in two places. In the facelet and in the managed bean as well. This two places are separated. I sould use constants to reduced the possibility of the mistyping. But it seems the `name` of the `f:param` does not evaluate EL expressions. (`passedParamValue` is always `null`). But if I directly wire the text 'paramName' to the `name` attribute, it works fine. Am I right or is there any way to use constants here?

Comment: JSF version and implementation? Tried latest ones? According to the docs https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/param.html it **should** accept EL. Did you debug and see if the method is called at all? Tried running your app in development mode (always do! (during development))

Comment: @Kukeltje I use Glassfish 5.0 (JSF 2.3). I "Debug the file" in NetBeans 8.2. And if I use a string literal, the page generated right, but with EL fails (run to a null pointer, the 'passedParameterValue' is always null). NetBeans 8.2 does not support JSF 2.3 yet, so could be the problem around that?